# Only one type of div is showing

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sql

I have this pie chart, I am trying to get it to toggle open a certain div that has a specific table that I need upon clicking a certain segment on the pie chart but have continuously failed. I am not sure if the click part of the code is correct because if I try the piece of code,
only the not delivered table shows and it does not matter which segment I am clicking. If I click delivered, It still shows the not delivered data

my PHP for the pie chart

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oatdistribution");

      //January
      $piesql = "SELECT Status, count(*) as Total FROM jan GROUP BY Status";
      $pieresult = mysqli_query($con,$piesql);
        
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pieresult))
    {
     $dataPoints[] = array("label"=>$row['Status'], "y"=>$row['Total']);
    }
```

my html for the pie chart

```
<div class="piepie">
    <div id="chartContainer" class="pie1"></div>
    <div id="chartContainer2" class = "pie1"></div>
    <div id="chartContainer3" class = "pie1"></div>
</div>
```

my html + PHP for the table

```
<div class="myTable" id="DevJan">
      <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
          <th>Type of Oat</th>
          <th># of Oat</th>
          <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oatdistribution");
                $tabsql = "SELECT OatDis.Name, OatDis.LivingCondition, OatDis.OatType, OatDis.NoOfOats, Jan.Status FROM OatDis INNER JOIN Jan ON OatDis.Name = Jan.Name WHERE Jan.Status = 'Delivered'"; 
                $data = mysqli_query($con,$tabsql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['Name']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['LivingCondition']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['OatType']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['NoOfOats']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['Status']."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
    <div class="myTable" id="NotDevJan">
      <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
          <th>Type of Oat</th>
          <th># of Oat</th>
          <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <?php
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oatdistribution");
                $tabsql = "SELECT OatDis.Name, OatDis.LivingCondition, OatDis.OatType, OatDis.NoOfOats, Jan.Status FROM OatDis INNER JOIN Jan ON OatDis.Name = Jan.Name WHERE Jan.Status = 'Not Delivered'"; 
                $data = mysqli_query($con,$tabsql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['Name']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['LivingCondition']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['OatType']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['NoOfOats']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['Status']."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

script for the pie chart

```
window.onload = function () {
    
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      click: TableStatus,
      animationEnabled: true,
      legend:{
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: "center"

      },
      data: [{
       click: onClick,
        indexLabel: "{label} ({y} people)",
        yValueFormatString: "#,##0.\"\"",
       indexLabelFontSize: 17,
       indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",
       indexLabelFontColor: "black",
       indexLabelLineColor: "black",
       indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
       type: "pie",
       showInLegend: true,
       legendText: "{label}",
       dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
     }]
   });

   chart.render();

  function onClick(e){
      if( e.dataPoint.dataPoints == 'Delivered'){
        $("#DevJan").show();
        $("#NotDevJan").hide();
      }
      else{
        $("#DevJan").hide();
        $("#NotDevJan").show();
      }
      chart.render();
    }
```

Comment: Code looks okay. Did you, just for testing purposes, put some text in your div instead of the chart? I mean, just to make sure that it really doesn't show up. It is still possible, that only the chart gets not rendered properly.

Comment: Note your table html is invalid. You are nesting  the new `<tr>` from the loop in an existing `<tr>`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just tried it. The words appear just not my pie chart. I tried it before without the table, everything worked fine. I wonder why it suddenly wouldnt show after including the table

Comment: have you checked the console for any errors?  I can't see the part where you call `showSlides` so i'm not sure what `n` actually is - can you show this bit?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue, there was an error code for my Pie Chart. This was just for testing, what I really wanted to do is insert a click event on the pie chart's segment. If that certain segment is clicked then the right div table should be toggled open but I keep getting errors with the if else part.

Comment: Let me edit back the question